# Phalcon mongodb update $pull

Tags: mongodb, phalcon

`{_id : ObjectId(...), name : "name", ids : [44, 1, 9, 11, 15, 66]}`

How to remove, for example, `15` form `ids` ???

Is this possible to use `$pull` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/ ?

Phalcon docs http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/odm.html#creating-updating-records

Comment: Don't really know because I do not use. But it seems there is a [`getConnection()`](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Collection.html) method when you dig through the collection interface documentation. This would appear to get the underlying driver connection from the dependency injection interface. Once you have the standard driver connection then you should be able to use all the methods supported [there](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php)

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/):

Your collection:

```
{_id : ObjectId(...), name : "name", ids : [44, 1, 9, 11, 15, 66]}
```

You can remove, "15" from the above "ids" array with a simple update:

```
db.yourcollection.update(
               { ids: "15" },
               { $pull: { ids: "15" } },
               { multi: true }
             )
```

The update consists of

- { ids: "15" }: Find all of these in your ids array.
- { $pull: { ids: "15" } }: "The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified query" -- in this case where value is 15
- { multi: true } : Simple multi flag to remove multiple occurrences found.

Hope that helps.